# My /usr/share/themes Folder Got Deleted?

Tags: themes

**Hi I am Keval **

My /usr/share/themes Folder Got Deleted. how can I restore them again and I have also restarted the pc 3 times

Thankyou In Advance
Keval Shah

Comment: How did it get deleted?

Comment: Acctually I dont know that exactly but when I started my laptop all the app layout was changed . when I checked the /usr/share/ folder then I saw that there was no theme folder and it was deleted

Answer (score 3):

You have to reinstall the packages which put files into the `/usr/share/themes` directory by using command below:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /usr/share/themes | sed 's/,//g' | sed 's|: /usr/share/themes||g')
```

Above:

- `dpkg -S /usr/share/themes` shows the list of comma-separated packages
- `sed 's/,//g'` - removes commas
- `sed 's|: /usr/share/themes||g'` - removes `: /usr/share/themes` in the end

Comment: Thankyou N0rbert For your Answer .... : )